# Escape characters in sed

Tags: sed

How do I escape a quote mark in sed. I have tried using the backslash, but sed continues to try and match the ' which I am trying to include in my string.

```
sed -i 's/vclist_2d_.*/'$X'\'/g' 1759_input.py
```

Comment: $X is a variable which I'm defining as part of a for loop. Basically I'm trying to using this to change the text `'vclist_2d_1.txt'` to `'vclist_2d_n.txt'` where n ranges from 1 to 10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a shell issue than a `sed` issue.  To get a single quote passed to a command (`sed` in this case), it either needs to be in a double-quoted string, or you have to use `\'` outside a single-quoted string.  For a single-quoted string, therefore, you have to use the sequence:

- `'...'\''...'`

  1. The first `'` after the ellipsis finishes the current single-quoted string.
  2. The `\'` embeds a single quote into the argument.
  3. The `'` resumes a single-quoted string.

In context, that means you should use:

```
sed -i 's/vclist_2d_.*/'"$X"\''/g' 1759_input.py
```

which replaces the `vclist_2d_.*` with the value in `$X` followed by a single quote, globally (though the global is pointless since the `.*` in the match eats up the rest of the line on the first match anyway).

You could simplify that, in this context, to:

```
sed -i "s/vclist_2d_.*/$X'/" 1759_input.py
```

The value in `$X` must not contain any slashes.

Answer (score 0):

for `'` in the replacement use `'\''` for a literal `'` substitution.

example

```
sed 's/vclist_2d_.*/'$X''\''/g' 1759_input.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X="B"; echo "abc" | sed 's/b/'"$X'"'/'    
aB'c
```